# How do I eliminate an element in my HTML form depending on a dropdown selection? (JS?)

Tags: javascript

In JS, how would I make a input field disappear depending on the first drop-down box selection?

Do I need to have JS in my html form and then a seperate JS function, say just before that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = document.getElementById('selectID');
var input = document.getElementById('inputID');

obj.onchange = function(){
    input.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use Javascript to do so. Specifically, either use `obj.style.display='none';` if you just want to hide them, or use  the `removeChild()` API to completely remove them.

Of course, the above needs to be done on a `onchange` handler (function) of your drop-down.